# why admob stop showing ad's while it's work before

Tags: admob

I have launch recently a new app working only with ad's of admob. The app is on release with official admob id, last week I received all ad's correctly but this week I have zero ad's ... I have touch nothing, I have no email of restriction no alerte...

It's normal ? I need fiability in match rate, without fiability user don't access to certain option or party of game without ad's. It's all the structure of the app who is questioning by this no fiability of match rate.